# How to knit a file using the console?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, kable

How can I knit the following R markdown to PDF using a function call?

````
---
title: '`r params$college` report'
params:
  college: 'Art & Business'
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = F)
```

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
mtcars %>% 
 kable( format = 'latex',  longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "condensed", font_size = 8) %>% 
  landscape(margin = c('1cm')) 
```
````

I thought  `rmarkdown::render('filename.Rmd')` would work, but I get an error, while it works when using the knit button in RStudio. Thus I was wondering if there are any differences between pressing the knit button and using `render`.

When I use `render()` I get this error message:

> /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m
> -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
> --output test.tex --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex
> --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'  ! LaTeX Error:
> Environment landscape undefined.
>
> Error: Failed to compile test.tex. See test.log for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not, at least not in general, and I have processed dozens of documents with this little script [render.r](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/render.r) which is part of [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler).  It really is just a wrapper around `rmarkdown::render()` picking up the filename(s) as argument(s).  You could just do
     `Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("yourfile.Rmd")'`
as well.

It also works with your example *provided I fix the error that is flagged*, ie the wrong argument `"condensed"` for `latex_options` which appears to no longer be valid.  I picked `"striped"` and got this two-page report:

[image]

If you tweak the table and/or suppress the code you can probably make it a one-pager as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reasons, it works when I run it from the terminal. But when running it from R: I fixed `latex_options` and still get the same error. I took a look at the log, the only thing I noticed is this `no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML`. I tried to reinstall maclatex but it doesn't solve the issue. I'm aware the issue might not be reproducible because I just tested the code on another mac and it works.

Comment: If you get a `dyn.load()` error with something like path not found, install the package at the path. If the path is `.../stringi.io` run `install.packages("stringi")`, then `install.packages("knitr")`. I had to do this even though the path in fact existed.